# Angularjs add properties to model with a filter?

Tags: angularjs

I have a timestamp which I want to format in a specific way. For example:

Today at 4:57:30pm (in a few seconds)

Now, I could output the timestamp with a filter and have the filter simply output the html.

However, I'd rather keep the html tags/classes in the template, and somehow have the filter modify the original data with some new properties I can output after the filter call in the template.

For example, I am using ng-repeat to go over an array of objects that look like this:

{timestamp: 123345236, something: 'asdf'}

I want to run a filter to make it look like this:

{timestamp: 123345236, today: 'Today at ', time: '4:57:30pm', relative_time: '(in a few seconds)'}

Then I can reference those new keys to output in my template.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by properties? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
app.filter("myFilter",function(){
    return function(input) {
      var arr = [];
      angular.forEach(input, function(value, key){
          value.newCustomProperty = "Custom property" + key;
          this.push(value);
        }, arr);

      return arr;
    }
});
```

Apply the filter to ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in data | myFilter">

</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3bvd8ms9/)

Comment: This will cause `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` check log

Comment: @Froxz: Updated with a fix. We need to ensure that we return the same array everytime digest cycle runs. Thanks

Comment: can you explain please? I have same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606743/angular-digest-loop-on-ng-style

Comment: @Froxz: please have a look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig. We need to ensure that we return the same object so that angular does not think the model has changed whenever a digest runs

Comment: Khanh, I know this but I'm looking to a solution where I can change element css without runing to digest loop