# Angular Digest Loop on ng-style / Dynamic Photo Grid

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a filter that changes filtered object. But when I'm using `ng-style="item.gridSize"`
My Filter: (The Algorithm for size Grid was taken (changed for my needs) from [Here](http://blog.vjeux.com/2012/image/image-layout-algorithm-facebook-reordering.html)

```
angular.module("custom.modules.photoGrid", []).filter('photoSearch', [function () {
    function getGrid(photos){
        var output = [];
        var HEIGHTS = [];
        var COLUMN_WIDTH = 227;
        var MARGIN = 6;
        var DELTA = 20;

        var size = window.innerWidth - 50;
        var n_columns = Math.floor(size / (2 * (COLUMN_WIDTH + MARGIN)));
        create_columns(n_columns);
        var small_images = [];

        function create_columns(n) {
            HEIGHTS = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                HEIGHTS.push(0);
            }
        }

        function get_min_column() {
            var min_height = Infinity;
            var min_i = -1;
            for (var i = 0; i < HEIGHTS.length; ++i) {
                if (HEIGHTS[i] < min_height) {
                min_height = HEIGHTS[i];
                min_i = i;
                }
            }
            return min_i;
        }

        function gridSize(i, is_big) {
            var size = {
                'margin-left': (MARGIN + (COLUMN_WIDTH + MARGIN) * i)+'px',
                'margin-top': (HEIGHTS[Math.floor(i / 2)] * (COLUMN_WIDTH + MARGIN))+'px',
                'width': is_big ? (COLUMN_WIDTH * 2 + MARGIN)+'px' : COLUMN_WIDTH+'px',
                'height': is_big ? (COLUMN_WIDTH * 2 + MARGIN)+'px' : COLUMN_WIDTH+'px'
            };
            return size;
        }
        function createGrid(data){
            if (data.length >= 2) {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    var column = get_min_column();
                    if (Math.random() > 0.8) {
                        data[i]['gridSize'] = gridSize(column * 2, true);
                        HEIGHTS[column] += 2;
                    } else {
                        small_images.push(i);
                        if (small_images.length === 2) {
                            data[small_images[0]]['gridSize'] = gridSize(column * 2, false);
                            data[small_images[1]]['gridSize'] = gridSize(column * 2 + 1, false);
                            HEIGHTS[column] += 1;
                            small_images = [];
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (small_images.length) {
                    column = get_min_column();
                    data[(data.length-1)]['gridSize'] = gridSize(column * 2, false);
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
        var grid = createGrid(photos);
        return grid;
    }


    return function(photos, search) {
        var filtered = [];
        if(!!search){ /**@case1 if only search query is present**/
            search = search.toLowerCase();
            for(var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++){
                if(photos[i].photo_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1){
                    filtered.push(photos[i]);
                }
            }

        }else {
            /**@case2 no query is present**/
            filtered = photos;
        }
        filtered = getGrid(filtered);
        return filtered;
    }
}]);
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="input.value"> <span>{{ results.length }}</span> Photo Found
<div ng-repeat='photo in photos | photoSearch:input.value as results track by photo.id' class="photo-item" ng-style="photo.gridSize">
                    <img ng-src="/photos/{{photo.url}}">
                </div>
```

A small explanation:
Every time `ng-model` `input.value` changed filter is runed and creates different grid for filtered array of photos. all dimensions are written inside `gridSize` and this cause digest loop.

What I've tried until now: I've moved my `ng-repeat` in directive, but this way I can't access `result.length` and `input.value`.

I've also tried a `bindonce` directive but using it like `bo-style="photo.gridSize"` doesn't change the grid after user search(and is logically right because is bidden only once, but values changed.

**So my question is how to make `ng-repeat` assign new `grdiSize` property without running in digest loop.**

**UPDATE:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uxntktd/14/)

**Working Fiddle:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uxntktd/15/)

Comment: Mhm, could you create a pnkr or fiddle to make your problem reproducible?

Comment: @lin Updated added JSFiddle (You can see in console) the error message

Comment: i think the way you are using ng-style is not correct. It should be something like: `ng-style="{'margin-left' : calculationLogic,  'margin-top': calculationLogic}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of issues. It was not exactly a `ng-style` problem, but rather than in each digest cycle your photos were calculating different style objects, causing another digest cycle to run.

Some issues I've found:

- Error in logic was giving 0 colums, thus causing size to give `NaN` when calculating `margin-top` and failing. To fix this, I added a default value from 1 column.
- your `Math.random() > 0.8` was giving different results in each time your filter function was executing. In each digest cycle, since `Math.random()` gives different results, it was forcing another digest loop (you were updating gridSize object - since there's a `$watch` for each element in the `ng-repeat` it detects the changes and forces one digest cycle), and so on. That was the error log in console.

I created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpuzjz85/) that works. The main changes are

defined a fixed random value for each photo, after declaring your array

```
$scope.photos.forEach(function(onePhoto){
    onePhoto.randomValue = Math.random();
  });
```

then in the filter you would check against this value

```
if (data[i].randomValue > 0.8) {
}
```

and set a minimum of 1 column when creating columns

```
var n_columns = Math.max(1, Math.floor(size / (2 * (COLUMN_WIDTH + MARGIN))));
```

Also (but I believe this occured only in your fiddle), there was no `photo_name` to filter for, so I used `id` instead.

you might want to fix the `NaN` problem with other default value, but at least now you know the problems with the console error.

If you wanted to update your randomValue everytime you executed the search, you could place a `$watch` over your `input.value`, move the code that iterates photos and creates random values into a function, and use that in the callback for that watch function. So everytime you update results in search, your grid uses different random values without causing interfering with digest cycle.
Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jpuzjz85/1/)

```
var updateRandomValues = function() {
    $scope.photos.forEach(function(onePhoto){
        onePhoto.randomValue = Math.random();
      });
  };
  updateRandomValues();
  $scope.$watch('input.value', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        updateRandomValues();
    }
  });
```

However, if you want to get different css style only when you get different results (keep in mind that if you type and get same results as before, it will update your grid layout anyway), what you should `$watch` is the results variable instead. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jpuzjz85/2/)

```
$scope.$watch('results', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        updateRandomValues();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi thank you for pointing out some issue, here is Updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3uxntktd/15/ I've moved everything to directive and created PositionService. Seems working.
Btw, sometimes on resize there 1 extra column that can't be filled with big images, but small image can be inserted, can you advise on that?